# Band Matrices and Operation counts.

Tags: matrices

Please help me to solve this problem.

1. Show that the number of multiplications  to factor a $M \times M$ matrix with band width $d$ , is of the order $Md^2/2$.

It is the Exercise problem of section $6(6.1)$ from: *"Numerical solution 
of PDE by finite element method"* by Claes Johnson.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to calculate the product of two $( M\times M)$ matrices $A,B$. A better approximation is $Md^2$ and it is a upper bound. In particular, it is the exact value if $d=1$.

Let $d=k_1+k_2+1$. Using the $i^{th}$ row of $A$, we obtain the $i^{th}$ row of $AB$ with at most $1+\cdots+(d-1)+d+(d-1)+\cdots +1=d^2$ multiplications. Then a upper bound is $Md^2$.

For instance, if $M=50, k_1=3,k_2=7$, then the exact result is $5378$ and the bound is $6050$.

Yet, perhaps you want the decomposition LU ?